# Отправка и обработка POST запроса в QT

Tags: c++, qt, post, qt4, twitter-api

Нужно отправить такой запрос с помощью qt 4.8

Resource URL
https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token
[image: img]

И получить такой ответ
[image: img2]

Я сделал вот так, но в итоге возвращается полная ерунда:

```
void Communicate::sendData_post()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"));

    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "My Twitter App v1.0.23");
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization","Basic " + (CONSUMER_KEY + ":" + CONSUMER_SECRET).toBase64() + "==");

    request.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip"); 

    QUrl params;
    params.addQueryItem("grant_type","client_credentials");


    connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(getResponse(QNetworkReply*)));   

    manager->post(request,params.encodedQuery());
}

void Communicate::getResponse(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
    int i;
    QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();    
}
```

И вот, что получается в итоге:
[image: img3]

Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
QByteArray bearer_token;
bearer_token.append(CONSUMER_KEY);
bearer_token.append(":");
bearer_token.append(CONSUMER_SECRET);

bearer_token = bearer_token.toBase64();
bearer_token.prepend("Basic ");

QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"));
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", bearer_token);

QHttpMultiPart *mpart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

QHttpPart part;
part.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader
    , "form-data; name=\"grant_type\"");
part.setBody("client_credentials");

mpart->append(part);

QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request, mpart);

mpart->setParent(reply);
```

Comment: Да, заработало, спасибо)

Comment: @АртёмПрокудин, пожалуйста!

Comment: А можно еще один вопрос?
По поводу header'a с перечислением:
`Authorization:
        OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog",
              oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg",
              oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D",
              oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
              oauth_timestamp="1318622958",
              oauth_token="370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb",
              oauth_version="1.0"`
Правильно, что разделителем в запросе будет "&"?

Comment: Используйте POST (там амперсанд не нужен), т.к. иначе запрос получится слишком длинный для GET.

Comment: Нет, я имел в виду другое.
Получается, просто через запятую их указать?
`QByteArray auth;
 
 auth.append("OAuth ");
 auth.append("oauth_callback=\"http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%3A3005%2Ftwitter%2Fprocess_callback\",");
 auth.append("oauth_consumer_key=\""+ CONSUMER_KEY + "\",");
 auth.append("oauth_nonce=\"" + generateUniqueString() + "\",");
 auth.append("oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",");`

Comment: Понял Вас. Не знаю, не делал. Но вообще, по идее, должно быть так, как написано в примере. Парсингом и преобразованием параметров, указанных в таком заголовке, должен заниматься сервер Твиттера. Если с запятой не получается, попробуйте с амперсандом. Если тоже не пойдёт, задайте новый вопрос.